# Quotes don't work in Careers search

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, jobs, search, quotation-marks

When doing a careers search, it appears that quotes don't mean anything when put in the search field.  One easy to find [example](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=%22Functional+Programming%22&range=20&distanceUnits=Miles&allowsremote=true).  The second result is [this](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/32998/mts-1-software-engineer-ebay?a=CZbbkpG&searchTerm=Functional%20Programming), which has the word "functional" in it, but not next to the word "programming".

Comment: Both links are broken now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s true, we made a change a few months back to SQL’s [FREETEXT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176078.aspx), for which boolean-ish expressions are less relevant. We give up specificity in exchange for greater (in our estimation) likelihood of returning something the user would find relevant.

(FWIW, we do parse boolean expressions on the backend but it doesn’t play a large role in the index’s weighting.)

That said, we know an audience of programmers like ourselves tend to prefer control over automagic, and we’re leaning to the automagic side at the moment. We revisit search often. We’ve got Elastic Search in several places and it’s likely to find its way to job search.